# While loop double condition of cell value and color condition

Tags: excel, vba, loops, while-loop

I am trying to create a rules for a "while" loop.

I want to loop while:

- the next "A" cells are not empty

And

- the background color of the next cells are different than 10092390.

I tried this VBA code but Excel doesn't accept it:

```
While (IsEmpty(Cells((Last + 1), 1)=False) And Not ((Cells((Last + 1),1)).Interior.Color) = 10092390)
```

Comment: Please do *not* edit questions in a way that invalidates answers given. By all means add information to the question as needed (or ask another question) but, if you invalidate answers, it breaks the Q&A nature of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want being in the loop, for the enounced conditions, you have to build conditions exactly vice versa... Please, try next example:

```
Sub testWhileCondition()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, Last As Long
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Last = 2
  While Not IsEmpty(sh.cells(Last + 1, 1)) Or sh.cells(Last + 1, 1).Interior.Color = 10092390
    Debug.Print sh.cells(Last + 1, 1).Address
    'do here whatever you need.....
    Last = Last + 1
  Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219311/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-vba-while-loop-double-condition-with-color-cond).

Answer (score 2):

```
IsEmpty(Cells((Last + 1), 1)=False)
              |--------|  |          'last+1/1 (cell address)'
        |------------------|         'cell content'
        |------------------------|   'check cell content against false'
|---------------------------------|  'is result of check empty?'
```

This is evaluating whether `Cells((Last + 1), 1)` is equal to `False` and then passing that into `IsEmpty()`, something that doesn't really make sense.

I'm pretty certain you need to rethink where your brackets are. You're probably better off checking the cell content itself for emptiness, something like:

```
Not IsEmpty(Cells(Last + 1, 1))
```

---

Possibly a better loop condition would be the greatly simplified:

```
While Not IsEmpty(Cells(Last + 1, 1)) _
And Cells(Last + 1, 1).Interior.Color <> 10092390
```

Comment: Yes sorry i just try so many condition i forbide to delete "=False" .

New code here:

 While (IsEmpty(Cells((Last + 1), 1)) And Not ((Cells((Last + 1),1)).Interior.Color) = 10092390)

Comment: @AntoineDargouge: as I mentioned: replacing `=false` by `not()` is a simplification. You might need to rethink the whole condition chain, including this simplification.

Answer (score 0):

There were quite some problems with your brackets, can you try the following:

```
While (Not (IsEmpty(Cells(Last + 1, 1))) And (Not (Cells(Last + 1, 1).Interior.Color) = 10092390))
```

For your information: while programming, it is common to replace `if(<something>=false)` by `if(not <something>)`